# How do I personalize Android Studio layout?

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-layout, configuration

I accidentally made some of the windows dissapear and then I tried to get them back going to
window -> restore default layout
but this only made it worse and now I can't see all the small tabs (terminal, run, logcat, project files, etc). I can only see the code like this: [image]
I'm working on mac, don't know if it's different or not.

I only know how to work with the layout I'm used to, something more like this:

[image]

Comment: Try this: View -> Appearance -> Tool Window Bars

Comment: Thank you!

For a moment I couldn't find that menu and forgot about it (then I panicked when I didn't find it inside Window instead of View)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this: View -> Appearance -> Tool Window Bars

I was looking in the ***Window*** tab instead of the ***View*** one